Jquery form thank you page url is not working
I'm attempting to submit a form using the POST method. Upon successful submission, the page should redirect to a designated thank-you page URL. However, despite the form being successfully submitted, the page remains unchanged.
Any help on this would be much appreciated.
Here is the code I tried.
    jQuery('.submit').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = jQuery("#form");
    var actionURL = form.attr("action");
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: actionURL,
        
         data: form.serialize(),
         dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
           
        }
    })
  return false;
});


When you debug, what specifically happens?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  On the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Using the script debugger and placing a breakpoint in the success function, is it reached?  If you add an error function, is that reached?

I added an alert also but it didn't reach. There is no error on console.

If you're not familiar with your browser's debugging tools, now is a great time to start.  The console, network tab, and script debugger are particularly useful here.  On the network tab you can observe the requests and responses.  With the script debugger you can place breakpoints to pause execution of the code and step through it line by line as it executes to observe its specific behaviors and variable values.

As a guess... In the code shown you identify the form in two different ways.  Once with .submit and once with #form.  Why?  Is the former not actually the form?  If the former is a submit button within the form then it doesn't have a submit event.  You'd attach this handler to the form itself.

debug the event handler first - ie jQuery('.submit').submit(function(e){ alert("submit")...  if that's not happening, then the href= clearly won't be happening.  "depsite the form submitting" - it's probably the form that's submitting, not your code.  Change the url in the ajax call to check.
